Tableau - Using Parameter as filter in switch worksheet method
I have multiple worksheets that setting-up a switch method by Frequency (Yearly, Quarterly, Monthly, Weekly, Daily). When select the parameter frequency value in filter box, it does not show what i filtered.

But one of my working dashboard the value of parameter is being selected.

I'm not sure if there's any configuration that i need to switch on version 2023.1.2, but this is puzzling me.  When i remove the working filter and re-add, it doesn't filter for any value at all.

In recent versions of Tableau, you can more easily control which views are shown when on a dashboard using a feature Tableau calls "dynamic zone visibility". You might still need a parameter, but control visibility on the dashboard layout pane instead of with a filter. So read about that feature, and beware about reading older instructions from earlier versions of Tableau - which were essentially working around the lack of the explicit zone visibility feature
